# Collision box to slow

Tags: c#, monogame

I've made the collision box for my player (and other blocks) and I'm now testing gravity and collision on the player. What I saw was that my collisionbox is updating slower than my player is moving.

It's not visual if he's just moving, but you can clearly see it when he's falling at a certain speed. (and it causes problems with the collision because the box updates slower)

This is for updating my collision box (and player):

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
{
    // collision box for player
    if (left)
    {
        collisionRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X + 10, (int)position.Y + 14, frameSize.X + 2, frameSize.Y + 20);
    }
    else
    {
        collisionRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X + 8, (int)position.Y + 14, frameSize.X + 2, frameSize.Y + 20);
    }
    // for player
    position += direction
}
```

This is for updating my player:

```
public override Vector2 direction
{
    get
    {
        Vector2 inputDirection = Vector2.Zero;
        keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();

        if ((keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) || (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)))
        {
            moving = true;
            walking = true;
            inputDirection.X -= 1;
            running = false;
            left = true;

            if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
            {
                speed = speedMultiplier;
                inputDirection.X -= 1;
                running = true;
            }
        }

        if ((keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) || (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)))
        {
            moving = true;
            walking = true;
            inputDirection.X += 1;
            running = false;
            left = false;

            if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift))
            {
                speed = speedMultiplier;
                inputDirection.X += 1;
                running = true;
            } 
        }

        if (!(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) && !(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) && !(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) && !(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)))
        {
            moving = false;
            walking = false;
        }

        if (stopping)
        {
            inputDirection.X = 0;
        }

        if (falling)
        {
            inputDirection.Y += 1f;

        } else
        {
            inputDirection.Y = 0;
        }

        return inputDirection * speed;

    }
}
```

Or do I also need to use a get; for my collisionbox instead of updating it in `Update()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Update()` method, you should be setting up the collision box after you add the vector `direction` to the player's `position`. Otherwise the collision box will always be at the player's position at the last update, not the current one. When the player has a high velocity (such as when falling), this will make it appear that the box is lagging behind.

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
{
    // for player
    position += direction

    // collision box for player
    if (left)
    {
        collisionRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X + 10, (int)position.Y + 14, frameSize.X + 2, frameSize.Y + 20);
    }
    else
    {
        collisionRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X + 8, (int)position.Y + 14, frameSize.X + 2, frameSize.Y + 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick anwser. Didn't think of that before.